# Why we need `int64` for MNIST labels in a loss function , from tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, mnist

The code is excerpted from [Tensorflow tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist.py). This function runs operations on MNIST datasets, a dataset of handwritten pictures of 0-9. Why cast labels to `int64`, I thought `int32`was enough.

```
def loss(logits,labels):
    labels = tf.to_int64(labels)
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        logits,labels,name='xentropy')
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy,name='xentropy_mean')
    return loss
```

Comment: Some of these conversions are to make TensorFlow use the same type as numpy when the data is fed as numpy arrays (numpy integers are int64 by default)

Comment: In that case, the conversion should automatically happen, right? I tested it with numpy when defining an array without specifying `dtype` and it by default takes it to be `int64`. Then, why bother casting beforehand?

Comment: if you feed `int64` to TensorFlow `labels` node which is `int32` then it will have to go through a downcast during each run call. IE, it will have to run logic to see if the fed value int64 fits inside the `int32` space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [documentation](https://github.com/ahangchen/TensorFlowDoc/blob/master/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard4/tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits.md#args) says it can be either `int32` or `int64`. So, it's up to you to choose one of those. Here, they preferred to choose `int64`.

Quoting from the documentation:

> `labels`: Tensor of shape `[d_0, d_1, ..., d_{r-2}]` and dtype `int32` or `int64`. Each entry in `labels` must be an index in `[0, num_classes)`. Other values will raise an exception when this op is run on CPU, and return `NaN` for corresponding corresponding loss and gradient rows on GPU.

Comment: So why they prefer int64 then?

Comment: I think it's for compatibility & efficiency reasons on 64-bit machines which are more common these days. In 32-bit machines, int64 can be represented using two 32-bit memory addresses.